# Use substrings of filename as parameters in for loop that builds aws command

Tags: bash, file-management

I'm trying to upload all files in a directory to s3 using dates in the filenames as parameters to create the s3 locations. Here's what I have so far.

```
for file in /home/ec2-user/clickparts/t*; do 
    year="${file:9:4}"
    month="${file:14:2}"
    day="${file:17:2}"
    aws s3 cp "$file" s3://mybucket/json/clicks/clickpartition/$year/$month/$day/
done
```

Below is the output for the file "the_date=2017-05-04"

```
upload: ./the_date=2017-05-04 to s3://mybucket/json/clicks/clickpartition/-use//c/ic//the_date=2017-05-04
```

I want to put the file in

s3://mybucket/json/clicks/clickpartition/2017/05/04/the_date=2017-05-04

Comment: So, does it work? Does it fail? How does it fail? What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? Any error messages? What do your file names look like? We can't know if your commands make sense if you don't tell us anything about them! Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon Edited for clarity of these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file "the_date=2017-05-04", your for loop will set the `file` variable to `/home/ec2-user/clickparts/the_date=2017-05-04`. If you take 4 characters from the 9th character, you get `-use`, which is what you see where your `year` variable is used.

One way to fix this is to take account of the number of characters in your path, and add the number of characters (in this case 26) to each of the start numbers when setting your year month and day variables.

Another way might be to change to the appropriate directory before the for loop (and change back after it finishes), then your for loop becomes `for file in t*; do`, which would set your `file` variable to what I believe you are expecting.

Comment: Also, the question is tagged with "loop-device" instead of "loop". I've tried editing the tag, but it doesn't let me, because I wasn't changing any text in the Question. ("It looks like nothing has changed") Is there something I'm missing, or is someone else able to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You can also run it through basename
`filename="$(basename -- "$file")"`